# Using AWS ruby-sdk with Inspec named profiles issue

Tags: inspec

Trying to clean up some testing for IaC using `Inspec`, But hardcoding `security_group_ids` is a no go for obvious reasons.

Im trying to use the ruby sdk instead to pull down the `id` based of a `name` (ie like you do with `Terraform` `data` resources).

But we work from `aws named profiles` and while Inspec can connect to named profiles when i run the test ie :

`inspec exec . -t aws://prod_account`

Is it possible from `Inspec` to link the call to `aws named profiles` to ruby code within a control?

Answer (score 0):

since inspec is written in ruby, you can embed any ruby code within your spec files. for instance, you can have a ruby code with an array and for each array have a spec code.

thus, you can implement a logic for collecting the security group ids and then iterate over them.

Comment: Hi, yes the code runs, but unless i have a default profile set up the ruby sdk code errors unable to connect. 

I can set up a named profile hardcoded in the ruby but inspec ignore thats

Ive tried running `lumigo-cli switch-profile` to use `inspec exec . -t aws://` but all the inspec is now failing and the ruby working :(

Comment: did you try to use an environment variable and fetch it within your ruby code?